# How do I send notification on post publication in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Where in the WordPress code can I add my own functionality to send notifications when a post is published by the moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme's functions.php file.

```
function your_callback() {
    global $post;
// Code here
}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'your_callback' );
```

Comment: Ok, and how can I send parameters to this function? If I want use some post data in my notifications?

Comment: Easy enough. Just globalize the $post object like so `global $post;` in the first line of the function. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) describes the object's properties.